# how to compare two PM times using twig

Tags: symfony, date, twig

i am trying to compare the current time with the open and close time of an entity Etablissement:

```
{% if etablissement.horraire |date('h:i:s') < date() |date('h:i:s') and etablissement.horraireF |date('h:i:s') > date() |date('h:i:s') %}
```

the problem of this code is, that it works with AM time, so if the current time is 15:00 and open at 08:00 close 22:00 he will compare 15:00 between the AM time(08:00 and 03:00)
Reference to [PHP: time - Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) i added p:

```
{% if etablissement.horraire |date('h:i:s P') < date() |date('h:i:s P') and etablissement.horraireF |date('h:i:s P') > date() |date('h:i:s P') %}
```

But, the  `P'` is not considered in the comparaison it is a simple string showed with the open&close times.
How can i compare two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use upper case for h: `H` so try with the format `H:i:s`. As example:

```
{% if etablissement.horraire |date('H:i:s') < "now" |date('H:i:s') and etablissement.horraireF |date('H:i:s') > "now" |date('H:i:s') %}
```

Hope this help